# Multiple part problem concerning the proof that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ by induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, induction

[image]

So I'm having trouble with $c,d$ and $e$.

For $c$ so far I have:

Inductive Hypothesis: $(\frac{n(n+1)}{2})^2 = (\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2})^2$ is that correct?

Comment: Induction hypothesis is $\sum_{k=1}^{m}k^3=\left(\dfrac{m(m+1)}{2}\right)^2.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\geq 1$, let $P(n)$ denote the following statement:
$$
P(n) : \sum_{k=1}^n k^3=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2.
$$

**(a):** $P(1)$ is the statement that $\sum_{k=1}^1 k^3 = \left(\frac{1(1+1)}{2}\right)^2$.

**(b):** $P(1)$ is true because $\sum_{k=1}^1 k^3 = 1 = \left(\frac{1(1+1)}{2}\right)^2$.

**(c):** Fix some $\ell\geq 1$ and assume that $P(\ell)$ is true where
$$
P(\ell) : \sum_{k=1}^\ell k^3=\left(\frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{2}\right)^2.
$$
That statement $P(\ell)$ is the inductive hypothesis.

**(d):** To be shown is that $P(\ell+1)$ follows where
$$
P(\ell+1) : \sum_{k=1}^{\ell+1} k^3=\left(\frac{(\ell+1)(\ell+2)}{2}\right)^2.
$$
Starting with the left-hand side of $P(\ell+1)$,
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^{\ell+1}k^3 &= \color{red}{\sum_{k=1}^\ell k^3}+(\ell+1)^3\tag{by defn. of $\Sigma$}\\[1em]
&= \color{red}{\left(\frac{\ell(\ell+1)}{2}\right)^2}+(\ell+1)^3\tag{by $P(\ell)$, the ind. hyp}\\[1em]
&= \frac{(\ell+1)^2}{4}[\ell^2+4(\ell+1)]\tag{factor out $(\ell+1)^2/4$}\\[1em]
&= \frac{(\ell+1)^2}{4}[(\ell+2)(\ell+2)]\tag{factor quad. polynomial}\\[1em]
&= \frac{(\ell+1)^2(\ell+2)^2}{4}\tag{multiply and rearrange}\\[1em]
&= \left(\frac{(\ell+1)(\ell+2)}{2}\right)^2,
\end{align}
we end up at the right-hand side of $P(\ell+1)$.

**(e):** Steps **(a)-(d)** show that the formula is true for all positive $n$ because we showed that $P(1)$ was true and that $P(\ell)\to P(\ell+1)$. This is what all we must show for mathematical induction to be a valid method of proof. We have shown this; thus, $P(n)$ must be true for all positive $n$.

Comment: A M A  Z I N G . Thank you

Comment: @user3325915 Glad you found it helpful. Hopefully others will as well. :)

Comment: @PaulHanson Thanks for the edit and cleaning up my carelessness. I'm so used to assuming something for $k$! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

No. The inductive hypothesis is $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^3 = {({{\frac{{n(n+1)}}{2}}})}^2 $, which we assume is true.

From there:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^3 +(n+1) = {({\frac{n(n+1)}{2}})}^2+(n+1)
$$
Edit - the above has a typo, it should be:
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^n k^3 +(n+1)^3 = \left ({\frac{n(n+1)}{2}}\right )^2+(n+1)^3
$$

Try to see if you can go on from here.

Comment: Are you sure you don't plug in $k+1$ for every $n$?

Comment: Yes. That's what you want to get to, from the induction hypothesis.

Comment: ok so I ended up with $\frac{n^4+2n^3+n^2}{4}$

Comment: and multiplying through by a $\frac{4}{1}$ I got  $n^2[ (n+1)(n+1)]$

Comment: so would I end up with $n^2 * (n+1)^2$ ?